# preg_grep matching incorrectly?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, pcre

My code:

```
$q = array('r%and_dy', 'cat09', '##$%%^');

$result = preg_grep('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $q);

print_r($result);
```

Using the same regular expression with javascript will only match 'cat09', but in php this returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => r%and_dy
    [1] => cat09
)
```

What do I have to write so that it only returns 'cat09'?

EDIT: you want to see the javascript. The javascript match function with the 'g' flag is the equivalent function of preg_grep in php, but it doesn't accept an array - here's a fiddle, which each item as a separate line. http://jsfiddle.net/64A5w/

EDIT: jsfiddle is down, so here is the the javascript equivalent. First I should mention, `preg_grep` only accepts arrays, and automatically returns global matches (it does not accept a g flag). Javascript `match` only accepts strings, and g must be specified.

```
var str = 'r%and_dy';
var result = str.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g);
document.write(result);
```

which displays: `r,and,dy`. The php equivalent would be passing preg_grep `$str = array('r%and_dy')`. It should return the same array But it returns `r%and_dy` as a single match (as shown above).

Comment: 'Using the same regular expression with javascript' show us your javascript code, changes are you haven't used the /g flag making it only match once.

Comment: What do you mean by using it in JavaScript?  Show your JS code

Comment: Or the JavaScript is anchored with `^$`.  If you don't want to match `r%and_dy`, use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`

Comment: I added a fiddle. @BenjaminGruenbaum php's preg_grep doesn't have a g flag.

Comment: My tablet only shows "loading the awesome" for jsfiddle, so I can't see what the js regex looks like, but if the same regex only shows cat09 in js js' regex implementation is severely broken.

Comment: @tink for `r%and_dy` javascript match() returns an array of matches - `r`, `and`, `dy`. But if I passed php an array of just `r%and_dy` it returns the same string as though it were a match.

Comment: @inorganik the fiddle isn't working for me either, would you mind trying jsbin.com or codepen.io ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I edited my question to show the javascript equiv, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are matching strings that *contain* one or more alphanumeric character. Try:

```
$q = array('r%and_dy', 'cat09', '##$%%^');
$result = preg_grep('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $q);    
print_r($result);
```

The `^` and `$` mean the start and the end of the string respectively.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

> Returns the array consisting of the elements of the input array that match the given pattern.

Comment: I wish there was something more similar to javascript `match` that essentially filters out a string but I don't think it exists in php

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by filtering out a string, if you have other questions feel free to ask them here in SO or in the SO PHP chat-room,

Comment: So with js you can take 'r%and_dy', use `match` on it, then `join('')` and you end up with 'randy' - filtering out string.